# tensorflow: is there a way to specify XLA_GPU with tensorflow?

Tags: python, tensorflow

The following code is used to specify device on which tf node is running

```
with tf.device('/gpu:0'):
  a = tf.constant([1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0, 6.0], shape=[2, 3], name='a')
```

I have already known:
[this post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52943489/11170845), [tensorflow doc](https://www.tensorflow.org/xla/overview) and [xla demo](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/examples/tutorials/mnist/mnist_softmax_xla.py)

What i want to know is:

Is there any way to specify XLA_GPU as the device on which tf node is running?

```
with tf.device('/XLA_GPU:0'):
  a = tf.constant([1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0, 6.0], shape=[2, 3], name='a')
```

executing the code above gives `ValueError: Unknown attribute: 'device' in '/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:/XLA_GPU:0'`

this is 100% reproducible on google colab.

Comment: Try `/gpu:0` or `gpu:0`.

Comment: try with `with tf.device("device:XLA_GPU:0")`

Answer (score 2):

Check that the device is there first by examining the device names in the output from the following:

```
from tensorflow.python.client import device_lib
device_lib.list_local_devices()
```

Once you've verified that 'XLA_GPU:0' is a device on your system use something like

```
with tf.device('/device:XLA_GPU:0'):
```

Obviously you can change the names.